# How to install VirtualBox in Windows 8.1

Tags: command-line, system-installation, virtualbox, virtual-terminal, cmd

I'm trying to install virtualbox on my PC, but every time I try to install it through the command line, it says that sudo isn't recognized as a legitimate command.

Comment: If you are trying to install it on Windows, *what are you doing* at Ask**Ubuntu**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused by the headline of this post... Are you using Linux and want to install virtualbox, or are you using Windows 8.1 and want to install virtualbox?

If using Windows, then correct sudo does not work, you want to download the windows file from here:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

and then just double click on the EXE to install it.  If you need admin privileges to install you will be prompted for the admin password.

I did a little googling and could not find a way that sudo could be removed from Linux, you can have your sudo privileges removed, but not the command itself. Again sudo does not work in Windows, I hope this helps.

Comment: `sudo` can be removed. Debian and Arch do not install `sudo` by default.